# Python 3.8.12 cannot import Scipy 1.7.3

Tags: python, scipy

I cannot import the Scipy package in python. I am using pretty much the latest Anaconda installation, and have quite a lot of packages installed and working fine, except for Scipy. When I try to import Scipy, this happens:

```sh
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>python
Python 3.8.12 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Oct 12 2021, 21:22:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 136, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\_distributor_init.py", line 59, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\.libs\libbanded5x.CBCBXIAYFUWOYCSBXUA2BT6W76FYX4C7.gfortran-win_amd64.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

Just for your information, I am using:

- Python 3.8.12
- Numpy 1.20.3
- Scipy 1.7.3

I did not try properly removing Scipy and reinstalling again, because removing it would also remove many, many other packages that I am actively using. I did, however, manually delete the entire scipy directory from the "site-packages" directory in Anaconda installation, and then reinstall scipy with pip. It did not help.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Degrading `scipy` into 1.6.2 can solve the problem.
In order to downgrade you need to do `conda install scipy=1.6.2`

Comment: Actually, that did not help either. However, after I created a new environment in Anaconda and installed only the packages that I needed, the following trio seems to be working with everything else I need: `Python=3.8.12, numpy=1.21.5, scipy=1.7.3`. Maybe all the other packages that are installed in the `base` environment are causing some kind of interference? I do not know. The only thing different in terms of these three packages between `base` and the new environment is the Numpy version. Thanks anyway for the hint.